# Keyboard shortcut for 'refactor' for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio (using IDEA key mapping), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> brings up the 'Refactor' menu.

How do I do the same in IntelliJ?

*On Windows.*

Answer (score 38, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>    = refactor this

in intelliJ IDEA version 11.0.2

Comment: I just switched from Eclipse to IDEA and I liked the "quick refactor" menu there because it was sooo easy to use. But now in IDEA the hotkeys after opening "refactor this" are just awful. They are numbers (1, 2, ...) instead of the letters, they are not customizable and the numbers mean different refactorings depending on what is selected. Why not just a fixed letter for each action like "c" for "extract constant"? The way it is in IDEA I must first hit "refactor this" hotkey and then look up in the menu if "extract constant" is hotkey 4, 5 or 6 in the context. I don't get this UX decision.

Comment: Plus one of the most used refactorings "inline" has no single shortcut at all in this menu.

Comment: Workaround: Create shortcuts with same first stroke and different sekond stroke for each refactoring. Works kind of like it is in Eclipse but doesn't show you a nice menu with all possible options of course.

Answer (score 12):

If you press on <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and type in the action you want to perform, it also shows the shortcuts keys. This way you can learn shortcuts much easier.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The range of refactoring options in IntelliJ is fantastic, right click in your editor and hit <kbd>R</kbd> to see the entire menu. You'll soon want to just use the keyboard shortcuts though; some of my favourites are:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> : refactor a method or variable name
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> : refactor a variable / field type
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> : extract a method
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> : introduce a variable

Answer (score 3):

You'll find the main refactoring actions are bound to keys, rather than the entire menu being associated with a keyboard shortcut. The cheatsheet shipped with IntelliJ (Help > Default Keymap Reference) was invaluable when I was trying to get my head around everything that was possible. ([Available online too!](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA8_ReferenceCard.pdf)).

I think you can probably get the refactoring menu in Windows by hitting the **Context key** (next to the Right Ctrl) and then **R** whilst your cursor is in the editor window. Not sure if a dedicated binding exists - I'm pretty sure you can't set one.

Comment: :(

I hate remembering the shortcuts to all the different refactorings - for me, I always liked just having a shortcut to the refactor menu itself.

Context Key - R isn't configurable :(

Comment: Hmm, doesn't Alt-R open the Refactoring menu? I think I use that a lot: Alt-R + X = extract method, Alt-R + N = inline. Besides, you'll quickly learn the direct shortcuts to common refactorings (Shift-F6 for rename etc).

Comment: You can also hit Control+Shift+A (Search for action) and type the name of the refactoring you want. That way you don't need to remember all the shortcuts and yet get to what you want fairly quickly.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> will pull down the menu.  For instance, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd> will allow you to pull up a method.

Comment: In Visual Studio, a smaller menu with only the relevant refactorings is displayed - it shows only refactorings that apply to the specific entity the caret is on. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Hm, just press ctrl+r - it does refractor pretty much anything? I switched keyboard shortcuts layout to Netbeans and tweaked it a little bit but I don't think it changed anything. True challange is "How to press DO REFRACTOR button in the usages window when you want to refractor some method used on several places WITHOUT using mouse".

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a the default macOS keys ( provided you have default macOS set on IntelliJ), 
they are going to be -

fn+shift+f6